# c++ stl: сортировка и копирование

Tags: c++, сортировка, stl, copy

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность средствами STL отсортировать вектор в новый вектор?

Что-то типа

```
std::vector<int> data2 = std::sort_copy(data1.begin(), data1.end(), [](int v1, int v2){...});
```

Просто не хочется писать следующий код:

```
std::vector<int> data2 = data1;
std::sort(data1.begin(), data1.end(), [](int v1, int v2){...});
```

А то начинает страдать чувство прекрасного от лишнего присваивания :)

P.S. исправил ошибку в параметрах `sort`

Comment: `std::partial_sort_copy` подойдет?

Comment: Во первых альгоритму сортировки не передаются итераторы разных контейнеров, во вторых  покажите что из себя представляет   data1?

Comment: @Croessmah,   из существующих  STL альгоритмов другого выбора и нет   в этом случаи.  Думаю std::partial_sort_copy и есть ответ

Comment: От `std::sort(data1.begin(), data2.begin()` мое чувство прекрасного вообще хотело застрелиться :)

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, виноват, опечатался, естественно что итераторы от одного объекта, я хотел написать `data1.begin(), data1.end()`

Comment: с 'std::partial_sort_copy' я про первые 2 параметра не понял - как он тогда должен выглядеть?

Comment: `как он тогда должен выглядеть` — `std::partial_sort_copy(data1.begin(), data1.end(), data2.begin(), data2.end(), [](int v1, int v2){...});`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не только можете копировать в другой контейнер все содержимое первого вектора в отсортированном виде, но и любую отсортированную партию:

```
std::vector<int> data1{84, 44, 12, 23, 34, 8, 7, 4},
                data2(data1.size());
auto f1 = data1.begin(), s1 = data1.end(),
     f2 = data2.begin(), s2 = data2.end();
std::partial_sort_copy(f1, s1, f2, s2);
```

теперь `data2`  содержит элементы  со значением из `data1` в отсортированном порядке, а `data1` не изменил свое состояние.

```
//data1: 84 44 12 23 34 8 7 4
//data2: 4 7 8 12 23 34 44 84
```

Например, мы хотим копировать  половину отсортированной последовательности,  по  критерию, отличную от `std::less<int>`(например в убывающем порядке). Тогда:

```
std::partial_sort_copy(f1, s1, f2, f2 + std::distance(f2,s2)/2, 
                      std::greater<int>());        
//data2: 84 44 34 23 23 34 44 84
```